# Compare two arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, google-places-api

I'd like to check which elements are equal in my two arrays, but can't get it working.
This is my code:

```
for (var i; i < bombs.length; i++) {
    for (var j; j < bombsDb.length; j++) {
        if (bombs[i].name === bombsDb[j].address) {
            console.log(bombs[i].name);
        } else {
            console.log("non-equal elements");
        }
    }
}
```

So the first array contains objects from the google places api and the second one contains data from my database.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [make it easy](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection)

Comment: "Fix my code" question? Anyway, is bombs.name really equal to bombsDb.address? Seems odd.

Comment: There's no question here; you just said "hey, fix my code." Please be clearer, as well.

Comment: And a "name" should equal a "address" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to initialize `i` and `j`;

```
   for (var i = 0; i < bombs.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < bombsDb.length; j++) {
            if (bombs[i].name === bombsDb[j].address) {
                console.log(bombs[i].name);
            } else {
                console.log("non-equal elements");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing can also be done using the `.not` selector from jquery. Check this:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var b = [4,5,6,7,8,9];

$(a).not( $(a).not(b).get() ).get();
```

This will return the following array

```
[4,5,6]
```

Comment: can you explain exactly what is happening in this code?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the initial assignment to `i` and `j` in your for loop.

```
//          here
//           v
for (var i = 0; i < bombs.length; i++) {
    // your loop
}
```

This causes the comparision to return false in the first iteration of the loop since `undefined < bombs.length` always return false, so it will not proceed.